# I don't understand this structure of the sentence

Tags: gerunds, licensing

> As committed as he is to improving the quality of education in urban school,

I don't understand why the word used is *improving*, not improve (root verb)

Answer (score 4):

To understand what is going on here, first let's undo the "As X as Y is" subordinating construction and recover a standalone sentence:

> He is committed to improving the quality of education in urban school

"Is committed to" is a *verb phrase*, acting as a single unit.  "Improving [...]" is its direct object.  It is a rule of English that in the construction *commit to [action]*, the *[action]* must be described using gerunds and not infinitives.  This rule doesn't have a rationale; when you have the choice between a gerund and an infinitive as a direct object, it's pretty much arbitrary which is correct (depending on the main verb: sometimes one, sometimes the other, sometimes both can be used and it doesn't matter, sometimes both can be used but the meaning is different).

[This article discusses gerunds versus infinitives at some length](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm) and goes into more detail about when you should use which.

Incidentally, "is" and "to" in this context are acting as pseudo-tense markers:

> *is X-ed* ≡ state X was established in the past and still pertains now
>
> commit *to* X-ing ≡ make a firm plan to X in the future and/or continually from now

Without them, you would have the very different

> He committed improvements to the quality of education ...

which indicates that he's *done* doing whatever he did to improve the quality of education, and connotes that whatever he did was *criminal* (! but seriously, *commit [act]*, without the *to*, is basically only used when *act* is a crime).

Comment: I believe that you missed the point. It is not the case between "He committed improvements" and "He is committed to improving". In this specific case, I believe that the use of "He is committed to improve" is equally valid.

Answer (score 3):

*Improving* in this sentence is the present participle of *improve*. It is a non-finite form, which means it is not inflected for person, number or tense.

The choice between the *ing* form and the *to*-infinitive can be a difficult one for foreign learners, and to understand the different uses fully, you really need to consult a qualified teacher of English as a foreign language, or a grammar book written for foreign learners.

Answer (score 0):

The first time I read this question, I didn't see any problem with either *As committed as he is **to improving** ...* or *As committed as he is **to improve** ...*. Both sound fine to me.

I don't know which grammar rule I could use to argue, but since this is very specific, Google is useful.

I searched for *BBC "committed to improving"*, and *CNN "committed to improving*, and found about 6 million and 4 million results. Here are some examples,

> Gulf Air *committed to improving* all aspects of products, services.
>   Sammy Wilson says executive remains *committed to improving* A5.
>   Speaking to BBC London's Tim Donovan Mr Johnson said he is *committed to improving* safety for cyclists ...
>   But he said President Pena Nieto “is very *committed to improving* the economic lot in Mexico.”
>   ... we continue to be *committed to improving* the health and well-being of a diverse Michigan community.
>   On the other hand, we are *committed to improving* the team ...

I searched for *BBC "committed to improve"*, and *CNN "committed to improve*, and found about 140 and 72 thousand results. Here are some examples,

> The BBC has *committed to improve* understanding in the following ways: ...
>   You have not *committed to improve* the website access information ...
>   ... the Media Action is *committed to improve* the quality of ...
>   Canadian Solar is *committed to improve* the environment ...
>   In 2010, Landesa and its partners *committed to improve* economic ...
>   “We are *committed to improve* the state of the human rights ..."

Although the number of "**committed to improving**" is overwhelming, I don't believe that we should rule out the use of "**committed to improve**". Besides, my searches are very restrictive (to either BBC or CNN). When I simply searched for "committed to improving" and "committed to improve", both in quotes, I will get about 39 million and 2 million hits, in that order.

It appears to me that even though the use of **committed to improving** is recommended, but **committed to improve** has become at least acceptable.